# Sharing files between Mac Mini and Ubuntu

Tags: macos, ubuntu, network-shares, file-transfer, shared-folders

I want to get files off a Ubuntu box (10.04) and transfer them to a Mac Mini.

I am connecting the two directly with a piece of network cable (it's not a crossover, but I am told the Mini can handle this). The Ubuntu box has Samba installed (Samba appears in the Synaptic Package Manager when I search for it). The Ubuntu box has no means of getting on the Internet so I can't download other packages.

When I create a shared folder in Ubuntu it doesn't show up in Mac OS. But the Ubuntu box appears in the 'Shared' section in Mac Finder.

Comment: Have you set samba up to share any directories ?

Comment: What does show up when you select the Ubuntu box from the 'Shared' section of the Mac's Finder?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really provided enough information; it sounds like it *might* be Samba not being set up properly, but I can only guess.

Comment: Sorry. What other information can i provide? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried connecting to the ubuntu server from the Mac?

- Open up Finder.
- Command-K to open Connect To dialog.
- Enter the IP address or hostname of the ubuntu
- In the new window select the share you want to connect to.